# How do I implement HTTP Streaming by utilising IIS Web Server for my application in C#/ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, streaming

How do I implement HTTP Streaming by utilizing IIS Web Server for my application in C#/ASP.Net?

Do I need to poll the web server from the client?

Comment: I think you're referring to http push

Comment: Is HTTP push possible with out the need for polling?

Answer (score 0):

Check [WCF streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx) as explained in msdn.